# Query with more than 29000 registers with sqlite pcl in xamarin doesn´t works?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this plugin to connect xamarin form with sqlite: `SQLITE PCL`

If I query the database with a few tables records it´s works correctly, but if I query tables with for example 29000 records, it starts looking for a good time and returns no data, but If I put limit 100 to the same query it works correclty.
 I think the solution would be something similar like `connect timeout` in web forms, but I don´t know how to do this with xamarin, how can I do this?

I do the same steps like in this page to connection:
[LINK TO CONNECTION SQLITE](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/)

I accept suggestions, thanks.

Comment: What is the return if you try to get a Count for that table? Can you please show how you are doing the query and the type of the table?

Comment: *Any* database query should probably use the `limit` clause as a matter of routine.  Walk through the database "page by page," retrieving only the rows that you need at that time.  (When the query returns less than the requested number of rows, you know the end has been reached.) **Also,** with SQLite, it is very important to *use transactions,* even for reading, since that's needed to get the "lazy read/write" behavior that you're probably used to.  Without this, SQLite will, by design, physically verify (repeat) every read and every write, greatly slowing things down.

Comment: @jzeferino I have not tried to make the count, but it is as if suddenly disconnected and appears an alert that says canot open file and the file path of the sqlite. I used the sqliteconnection. My query is very simple (select * from MyTable) but if I do this (select * from MyTable limit 100) it works correctly

Comment: @MikeRoninson , Thanks for yor answer, do you have any example for what you explain? I understand that sqlite hide the counter and then when it reaches the number ir restart